# Json returns Null instead some datas

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, wordpress

I'm trying to display in a `TextView` the text in this page: http://www.oscarilfilm.com/oscar/
using json, php and mysql. I created a json.php to fetch data from db and encode the data in json using this:

```
<?php
$host="XXXXX"; //replace with database hostname 
$username="XXXXX"; //replace with database username 
$password="XXXXX"; //replace with database password 
$db_name="XXXXXX"; //replace with database name

$con=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql = "select * from emp_info"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$json = array();

if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$json['emp_info'][]=$row;
}
}
mysql_close($con);
echo json_encode($json); 
?>
```

And it goes. But when i try change the query to display that post i get this: http://www.oscarilfilm.com/newjson.php and exactly this for OSCAR page: `{"id":"39","post_title":"Oscar","post_content":null}`
but it's impossible! it can't be null! there is some content! Why? I'm using wordpress as cms.

Comment: Obviously it is possible as it happens. The question you should ask yourself is why is it null ? is it null in the database in the first place ?

Comment: no, in the database there is the text! And this is strange too! I can't find the problem

Comment: @A.S. i'm waiting for your response

Comment: Well, if the data isn't stored in the database, then that's were your problem is, you should show us your code inserting the data in the DB, not the one selecting it which seems to work as it should.

Comment: Simply, i created a `page` in wordpress and i wrote that text.. When i go in `phpMyAdmin` and i run the query `SELECT id,post_title,post_content FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'page' AND post_status = 'publish'` the result is perfect.. i can view the post published and also that post `39 Oscar Oscar Klein nacque a Graz il 5 gennaio del 1930. M...` (39 is the id).. so..why in the json it's wrong? you need something else?

Comment: I can't understand.. same query, in phpMyAdmin i get the right result with text.. with json not!!